# How to have a function called when Enter key is pressed in a guizero application?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, guizero

How do you call a function when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed in a python guizero application?

For reference I've created a form that takes input from a barcode scanner and on the event of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key being pressed it will insert the input into a database.

Here is an example of the `TextBox` and how the function should work.

```
def enterKeyClicked():
    dbInsert()

input = TextBox(app, width=30, align="top")
```

I checked the guizero github pages [documentation for events](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/events/), but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function on key press using `.when_key_pressed` as mentioned in the docs.

```
def enterKeyClicked(event):
    if event.key == "\r":
        dbInsert()

input = TextBox(app, width = 30, align = "top")
input.when_key_pressed = enterKeyClicked
```

When you press any key, `enterKeyClicked` is called and a [guizero `EventData` object](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/events/#event-data) is passed to it. You can use the `.key` attribute of the event to get the character of the key pressed. If the key pressed is <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the character is `"\r"`. This is the python character for a carriage return, which is returned when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once you've checked the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has been pressed, you can then call `dbInsert()`.